# Prevent HTTP request caching in Node.JS through Heroku

Tags: node.js, caching, heroku

I'm building a slack web hook that periodically grabs the top sales from /r/GameDeals and posts them to slack. In the past week, however, these requests have been returning the same body as the previous day. I am not storing the data anywhere, simply GETing it, parsing it, and then POSTing to slack. Here is my code:

```
request('https://www.reddit.com/r/GameDeals.json', function (error, response, body) {
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
   console.log('Successfully retrieved /r/GameDeals');
   var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
   var toSend = "Here are today's sales: \n";

   // grab the top 5 deals from GameDeals
   for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
     toSend += postString(bodyJSON['data']['children'][i]);
   sendToSlack(toSend);
 } else
   console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
});

function sendToSlack(toSend) {
  var text = { text: toSend };
  request.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/AAAAAA/BBBBBBB/CCCCCC',
             {body:JSON.stringify(text)});
  console.log("POSTed: " + toSend);
}
```

Looking at the last two days of heroku logs, it shows the same `POSTed:`.

```
2015-11-08T17:05:00.130635+00:00 app[web.1]: Performing daily sales check
2015-11-08T17:05:00.138196+00:00 app[web.1]: Checking sales for games in Firebase
2015-11-08T17:05:00.718358+00:00 app[web.1]: Successfully retrieved /r/GameDeals
2015-11-08T17:05:00.722763+00:00 app[web.1]: POSTed: Here are today's sales:
2015-11-08T17:05:00.722766+00:00 app[web.1]: - [GOG.com] BIG FALL SALE (Day 5) -- 2 new bundles (Settler's Pack &amp; Shots Fired), with new daily deals incl. Runaway series at 80% off; Syberia, Far Cry, LEGO Harry Potter games at 75% off and more -- DRM-free [<http://www.gog.com/|link>]
2015-11-08T17:05:00.722768+00:00 app[web.1]: - [Best Buy] Save $25 on a select game when you purchase Fallout 4, Tomb Raider or Call of Duty: Black Ops III [<http://www.bestbuy.com/site/offer/139091/pcmcat748300699145.c?id=pcmcat748300699145&amp;|link>]
2015-11-08T17:05:00.722769+00:00 app[web.1]: - [Target] Buy two get one for free has finally arrived! (3 for the price of 2) [<http://weeklyad.target.com/promotions?code=Target-151108&amp;page=1|link>]
2015-11-08T17:05:00.722770+00:00 app[web.1]: - [Best Buy] Buy a PS4 Console Bundle and get Fallout 4 and a Controller Charging Station for Free [<http://www.bestbuy.com/site/promo/ps4-offer-147984?|link>]
2015-11-08T17:05:00.722771+00:00 app[web.1]: - [GamersGate] Rocksmith 2014 ($10/€7.50/£6 | 75% off) | Steam, Worldwide [<http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-RS2014/rocksmith-2014|link>].1]: State changed from starting to up

...

2015-11-09T17:05:00.301154+00:00 app[web.1]: Performing daily sales check
2015-11-09T17:05:00.316703+00:00 app[web.1]: Checking sales for games in Firebase
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520064+00:00 app[web.1]: POSTed: Here are today's sales:
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520070+00:00 app[web.1]: - [GOG.com] BIG FALL SALE (Day 5) -- 2 new bundles (Settler's Pack &amp; Shots Fired), with new daily deals incl. Runaway series at 80% off; Syberia, Far Cry, LEGO Harry Potter games at 75% off and more -- DRM-free [<http://www.gog.com/|link>]
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520072+00:00 app[web.1]: - [Best Buy] Save $25 on a select game when you purchase Fallout 4, Tomb Raider or Call of Duty: Black Ops III [<http://www.bestbuy.com/site/offer/139091/pcmcat748300699145.c?id=pcmcat748300699145&amp;|link>]
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520073+00:00 app[web.1]: - [Target] Buy two get one for free has finally arrived! (3 for the price of 2) [<http://weeklyad.target.com/promotions?code=Target-151108&amp;page=1|link>]
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520074+00:00 app[web.1]: - [Best Buy] Buy a PS4 Console Bundle and get Fallout 4 and a Controller Charging Station for Free [<http://www.bestbuy.com/site/promo/ps4-offer-147984?|link>]
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520076+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-11-09T17:05:10.520075+00:00 app[web.1]: - [GamersGate] Rocksmith 2014 ($10/€7.50/£6 | 75% off) | Steam, Worldwide [<http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-RS2014/rocksmith-2014|link>]
2015-11-09T17:05:10.511322+00:00 app[web.1]: Successfully retrieved /r/GameDeals
```

I'm not sure if this is Heroku caching the response to my requests and just giving me back the same body as the last time it received or what. My bot has another function that allows it to look up a specific game and POST back to slack whether or not that specific game is on sale. When I do that, however, it seems to reset this caching process and the next day returns new queries. This function also uses the `request` npm.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that Heroku would cache requests FROM your service, it wouldn't provide you or them any benefit. It would also be very difficult for Heroku to do something of this nature, as they'd need to catch your request, and hold a mirror of a __huge__ amount of http responses. I'd assume that reddit only updates that JSON on a schedule, though I'm not certain, that would make much more sense than Heroku caching requests made by your service.

Comment: You can prove that its not heroku caching by adding some meaningless and random GETparam to the end of the URL. Ex. `https://www.reddit.com/r/GameDeals.json?stuff=randomData`. The parameter will just get ignored, but any caching mechanism will likely assume that the response would have changed in relation to that parameter.

Comment: @tsturzl I had not worded my question properly in the initial post, it has been fixed. What I meant to say was that I was suspicious of Heroku caching the response and simply giving me the same response when that request was made. 

I don't believe the reddit JSON is only updated once in a while, because I have made a direct request from my browser right after the Heroku request and received the proper updated response.

Comment: Also, if I included that GET parameter and the responses are fresh every time, wouldn't that be proving that Heroku was caching the responses otherwise? Because this would imply Heroku caches on simple requests.

Comment: It would prove that heroku is caching if adding a junk data param works. I can't imagine any other way of caching GET calls other than caching based on the URL itself. So if heroku is caching your request's responses then I'm 99% sure that would work. I'm still skeptical to think that they would do this, especially with the popularity of using third-party REST APIs, though I could be wrong.

Comment: The HTTP standard doesn't provide a way to uniquely identify web content other than the URL, and the content can be tagged or otherwise cache controlled, but its still referenced by its URL. In the browser an added URL param means that content is cached separately from the same URL without the param. And to cache `/GameDeals.json` and `/GameDeals.json?randomStuff` as one in the same is a horribly bad idea. Because that param is provided exclusively with the intention that the param is going to change the outcome of the response.

Comment: I'm really baffled that it worked. I was under the impression that you'd try the suggestion, it would fail, and that it would prove that heroku didn't cache. That was confusing wording I used, sorry about that. I'm really shocked that Heroku can cache a HTTPS connection, if it were to terminate SSL for reddit it would throw a cert error. I'm scratching my head right now.

Comment: @tsturzl I have yet to test it out yet! sorry if my wording made it seem like that. I was just getting the facts straight before I implement that change and see if it fixes the issue. I'll let you know when I do.